# QuoteState does not exist?

Tags: c#, namespaces, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am developing for Dynamics CRM 2013. I try to change the state of a Quote, but it seems that QuoteState is not found.
I try to use QuoteState.Active, but I get the error: "The name 'QuoteState' does not exist in the current context".
These are the namespaces I use:

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xrm;
```

What namespace am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

*Edit:*

This is the function where I am trying to use it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Activates the Quote
/// </summary>
/// <param name="quote">The quote</param>
/// <param name="xrm">The Xrm Service Context</param>
private static void ActivateQuote(Quote quote, XrmServiceContext xrm)
{
    SetStateRequest activateQuote = new SetStateRequest()
    {
        EntityMoniker = quote.ToEntityReference(),
        State = new OptionSetValue((int)QuoteState.Active),
        Status = new OptionSetValue(3)
    };
    SetStateResponse activateResponse = (SetStateResponse)xrm.Execute(activateQuote);

    // Save
    xrm.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Activated the quote...");
}
```

If I use State = new OptionSetValue(1) it works, so it is just that QuoteState is missing.

Comment: you need add reference. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa613627.aspx

Comment: I have googled, without any result. Also have I added references, but that didn't do the trick..

Comment: @Jowser would need to see more of the code including how you are using QuoteState.Active. Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309346.aspx) will help

Comment: I added the code where I use it. It seems that a reference or namespace is missing, but I can't see which one.

Answer (score 1):

`QuoteState` is a custom enum created when you use early-bound programming.
This means you need to run the Code Generation Tool (`CrmSvcUtil.exe`) from the SDK.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx

Just for information, this will the enum generated by the tool:

```cs
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CrmSvcUtil", "5.0.9690.3339")]
    public enum QuoteState
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Draft = 0,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Active = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Won = 2,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Closed = 3,
    }
```